# clicking one button to simulate clicking multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have a slew of buttons in different levels within a nested JQuery accordion.  This is functioning kind of like a phone book, and when buttons are clicked, numbers are added to a communication tool.

I was hoping to put a button at the top of each sublevel in the accordion that would add all of the rest of the buttons within that sublevel to the "To:" field.  I imagine there is an elegant way to do what I would otherwise be accomplishing by brute force in an ugly manner.  Thanks!

```
  <div id="accordion-nest">
  <h3>First group</h3>
      <div>
        <button id="allGroupOne">Add all of Group One</button>   <-----Button I want
        <button id="Guy1">Biff 555-1111</button> 
        <button id="Guy2">Tagg 555-1112</button> 
        <button id="Guy3">Mitt 555-1113</button> 
          ......
      </div>
    <h3>Second group</h3>
      <div>
        <button id="Guy13">Jeb 555-2222</button>
    </div>
          <h3>Third group</h3>
      <div>
        <button id="Guy33">Uncle Jesse 555-99999</button>
      </div>
  </div>
```

JS/JQuery

```
$('button').click(function () {

    var last8 = (this.textContent).slice(-8);  

    if (pageNames == '') {
        pageNames = (this.textContent).slice(0, -8);
    } else {
        pageNames = pageNames + " " + (this.textContent).slice(0, -8);
    }

    if ($('#pageTo').val() != '') {
        $('#pageTo').val($('#pageTo').val()+', '+ areaCode + last8); 
    } else {
        $('#pageTo').val(areaCode+last8);    
    }
}
```

Comment: the fake names in your phone book example made my day.  I dont know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add the same class to all the 'Add All' buttons:

```
<button class="allGroup">Add all of Group One</button>
```

And would also add the same class to all the other phone buttons:

```
<button class="phone" id="Guy1">Biff 555-1111</button>
```

Also, add a class to the `div`s that contains each group, like this:

```
<div class="groupContainer">
```

Then, this would be the jquery when clicking an 'Add all' button:

```
$(".allGroupOne").click(function(){
   var $parent = $(this).closest('.groupContainer');  //The parent div
   $parent.find(".phone").trigger('click');  //This simulates each button click
});
```

That's it!

Cheers

Comment: Wow, fast reply. In the time it took me to refresh the site, you already had this answer up.  This is working great for the names, but it is trying to add the "Add all of Group One" button to the "To:" field despite the fact it doesn't carry the .phone class.

Comment: Changed the $('button') to $('button.phone') and that fixed the problem.  However, I still don't understand why it was trying to add the "All Group One" button to the "To:" field.  Was it trying to add everything in the whole div and not just the .phone classes within the div?